# Google sheets equivalent to Excel Clear All?

Tags: google-sheets

In Excel, selecting a range and pressing the Del key is equivalent to 'Clear Contents' and leave the formatting unchanged. But there is also a 'Clear all' option that clears contents/formatting/whatever.

Where is that 'Clear all' command in GSheets ?

I guess I could write a macro that does both a clear contents and remove formatting, but I suppose that would not be undoable, so it would be an inferior solution, compared to a native command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "Enable compatible spreadsheet shortcuts" enabled, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> clears formatting, and the <kbd>DELETE</kbd> key (to clear contents) is right next to <kbd>\</kbd>.

So your *custom* "Clear All" keyboard combo could be:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd><kbd>DELETE</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I found out that on my french keyboard the Ctrl+\ is in fact Ctrl+*, so I have a solution, on Windows PC  AND it works on Chromebook too. Lucky me.

Comment: That's perfect / parfait!

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge there is not a standard keyboard shortcut to clear cell contents or clear all, and as you pointed out there is one to clear formatting...there are options.  If you open a Google Sheet > go to Help from the menu,then keyboard shortcuts, make sure to turn on "Enable compatible spreadsheet shortcuts" then there are a couple of shortcut option for "Delete Values".

I work on a PC, once enabling compatible spreadsheet shortcuts I was able to do the following:

Alt+E,A,C worked to clear the contents without clearing the formatting
Alt+E,V worked to clear the contents without clearing the formatting
Alt+H,E,C worked to clear contents and formatting

On a side note, if it is the same fields you want to clear just the contents you could record a macro or use a script to clear certain fields only. Good luck, I hope this works for you.